# Ionic3, AngularFire - Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire5

I have been following an outdated tutorial ([this playlist in particular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHTBnTg4rno&list=PLtKjv92L0ihAJ90_NbqCINRu4uKy3RJJU&index=13)) and I got lost switching between AngularFire 4.0 and AngularFire 5.0.
It's a simple CRUD application which implements Firebase.
The code is uncouth, but I am able to view and post to the database.

I'm trying to delete an item from a node using the key in firebase, but I'm getting the error

`Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'.`

Here is my `.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Matatu } from '../../models/matatu/matatu.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-owner-dash',
  templateUrl: 'owner-dash.html',
})

export class OwnerDashPage {

  matatuListRef$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase, public actionShtCrtl: ActionSheetController) {
    this.matatuListRef$ = this.database.list('matatu-list').valueChanges();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    //
  }

  selectMatatu(matatu: Matatu){
    this.actionShtCrtl.create({
      title: `${matatu.matNumberPlate}`,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          handler: () => {
            //
          }          
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.$key);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            //
          }
        }
      ]
    }).present();
  }


}
```

And here the `.html` code that displays the records.

```
...
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let ma3 of matatuListRef$ | async" (click)="selectMatatu(ma3)">
      <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">{{ma3.matNumberPlate}}</h2>
      <h3>Driver: {{ma3.matDriver}}</h3>
      <h3>Status: {{ma3.matStatus}}</h3>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
...
```

I know `FirebaseListObservable` was refactored to `AngularFireList`, but I assigned my variable to the type `Observable` instead.

`matatuListRef$: Observable<any[]>;`

Bottom line, I get the error `TypeError: _this.matatuListRef$.remove is not a function` on the browser's console when I try to delete the record.

How can I resolve this? 
All suggestions and approaches are highly welcomed,but I would really appreciate it if the solutions focused on using `AngularFireList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove()` function is present on the list reference retrieved from Firebase and *not the Observable* from `valueChanges()`.

You need to set

```
this.matatuListRef$ = this.database.list('matatu-list');
```

Secondly, you will not get `$key` from `valueChanges()` either. You need to use `snapshotChanges()` in order to retrieve keys and values.

```
this.matatuListAsync = this.matatuListRef$.snapshotChanges();
```

instead of

```
this.matatuListRef$ = this.database.list('matatu-list').valueChanges();
```

You can  use `this.matatuListAsync` in the `*ngFor` in the HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let ma3 of matatuListAsync$ | async" (click)="selectMatatu(ma3)">
      <h2 style="font-weight: bold;">{{ma3.payload.val().matNumberPlate}}</h2>
      <h3>Driver: {{ma3.payload.val().matDriver}}</h3>
      <h3>Status: {{ma3.payload.val().matStatus}}</h3>
    </button>
  </ion-list>
```

and finally in your `remove()` call,

```
        this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.payload.$key);
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you. When I use `this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.payload.$key);` as my remove call, everything is deleted from the DB.

Comment: I'm getting this `Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Matatu'`

Comment: If everything is deleted for the first time..it would be empty.. are you sure the keys were correct?

Comment: Ahhh! Right on! I see where I went wrong. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: `this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.payload.$key);` should be `this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.key);` or `this.matatuListRef$.remove(matatu.payload.val().$key);`